# How do you use aggregated values within PySpark SQL when() clause?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, scalar

I am trying to learn **PySpark**, and have tried to learn how to use **SQL when()** clauses to better categorize my data. (See here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-case-when-otherwise-example/) What I can't seem to get addressed is how to insert actual scalar values into the when() conditions for comparison's sake explicitly. It seems the aggregate functions return more tabular values than actual float() types.
I keep getting this error message *unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'method'* 
    When I tried running functions to aggregate another column in the original data frame I noticed the result didn't seem to be a flat scaler as much as a table (*agg(select(f.stddev("Col")) gives a result like: **"DataFrame[stddev_samp(TAXI_OUT): double]"***) Here is a sample of what I am trying to accomplish if you want to replicate, and I was wondering how you might get aggregate values like the standard deviation and mean within the when() clause so you can use that to categorize your new column:

````
samp = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("A","A1",4,1.25),("B","B3",3,2.14),("C","C2",7,4.24),("A","A3",4,1.25),("B","B1",3,2.14),("C","C1",7,4.24)],
    ["Category","Sub-cat","quantity","cost"])
  
    psMean = samp.agg({'quantity':'mean'})
    psStDev = samp.agg({'quantity':'stddev'})

    psCatVect = samp.withColumn('quant_category',.when(samp['quantity']<=(psMean-psStDev),'small').otherwise('not small')) ```
````

Comment: Try this psCatVect = samp.withColumn('quant_category',.when(samp['quantity']<=(psMean-psStDev),.lit('small')).otherwise(.lit('not small')))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psMean and psStdev in your example are dataframes, you need to use collect() method to extract the scalar values

```
psMean = samp.agg({'quantity':'mean'}).collect()[0][0]
psStDev = samp.agg({'quantity':'stddev'}).collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept searching and had the collect() at one point, but didn't realize I needed to use the indexes. I assume due to this being a dataframe, one needs to specify both the first row and column; hence the "[0][0]"?

Answer (score 0):

You could also create one variable with all stats as pandas DataFrame and reference to it later in pyspark code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

stats = (
    samp.select(
        F.mean("quantity").alias("mean"), 
        F.stddev("quantity").alias("std")
    ).toPandas()
)


(
    samp.withColumn('quant_category', 
                F.when(
                    samp['quantity'] <= stats["mean"].item() - stats["std"].item(), 
                    'small')
                .otherwise('not small')
               )
    .toPandas()
)
```

Comment: Thank you Pav3k, so would the "item()" replace the [][] in this case?

Comment: Yes and that is because data type is different. 
stats is pandas DataFrame with only one row so if you type stats["mean"] you have returned pandas Series of size 1. Because this is only 1 element, you can use stats["mean"].item() to extract scalar value. 
If you had more than 1 row in there, that .item() method would return ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar.